# What does "operation complete" mean in Netty

Tags: java, netty

My question in fact is:

When `ChannelFutureListener.operationComplete` is called and `Future.isSuccess()` is `true` (within the aforementioned method, ofc), is this guarantee that the remote party has received the message?

Concrete example:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
        m_Context.writeAndFlush(toByteBuf(message)).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) throws Exception {
                if (f.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Remote party received message"); // is this safe to assume?
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Can we say that if code enters `if (f.isSuccess()) {..}` block that the message has reached it's destination?

Any answer is highly appreciated, but citing some sources would be nice as well :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It basically means exactly what the name implies, the operation you requested was complete. In the case of `writeAndFlush(...)` it means the `write(...)` / `writev(...)` syscall completed and so was transferred to the kernel network stack, nothing more.

So there is no guarantee that the remote party has received the message (it`s just how tcp works). If you need to have a guarantee you will need to add something to your protocol (like an ACK message).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't have asked for a better source :)